# Анимация svg (Волна)

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

```html
<svg id="bg"viewBox="0 0 1440 761" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M1150 8.61221C843.181 111 842.5 458.768 441.962 309.552C303.655 258.027 156 309.891 -2 358.578V402.142C-2 402.142 307 260.5 606.5 613.5C906 966.5 1440 575 1440 575V93.9001C1322.5 37.0415 1272.82 -22.6491 1150 8.61221Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear_2_39)"/>
                    
                    <defs>
                        
                    <linearGradient id="paint0_linear_2_39" x1="1318" y1="521.112" x2="187.078" y2="644.159" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                    <stop stop-color="#590D56"/>
                    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#8C1688"/>
                    </linearGradient>
                    </defs>
                    </svg>
```

Господа, прошу помощи - есть svg, моя задача анимировать изображение так, чтобы по обеим сторонам (сверху и снизу) были небольшие волны.

В сети много вариантов, как сделать волны, но они все односторонние.

Этот svg будет фоном на сайте.

Пробовал keyframes и transform - ничего не вышло, не нашёл там необходимого оператора.

Прошу помощи практической или подсказки, что загуглить и где, что найти.

Comment: https://codepen.io/felixhornoiu/pen/JjmVZw посмотрите в этом примере как здесь сделан этот эффект

Comment: Другими словами нужно несколько состояний для этой анимации, 1,2,3,3,2,1 или даже больше